# Node/Express Request Query

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an endpoint that looks like this.

```
// GET /api/logs/
app.get('/api/logs', function (request, response) {
  if (request.query.reverse === true) {
    response.send((mainModule.logs).reverse());
  }
  else {
    response.send(mainModule.logs);
  }
});
```

The response is an array of objects, and I want the order to be determined by the query param 'reverse' boolean. Right now the query doesn't appear to be doing anything. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify, `my query doesn't appear to be doing anything`? Does that mean neither statement in if or else block is getting executed? If so that means your function isn't getting called which would be a problem in the routing url.

Comment: The else was executing every time. I changed the operator to look for 'true' as a string, and it's all working now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Querystring values are always returned as strings, so you should check for `reverse === 'true'` rather than `reverse === true`. This is because Express's req.query pulls directly from Node's querystring parser (code [here](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/lib/middleware/query.js#L16)). If you run the following in Node, you'll see that the result returns a string rather than a boolean for the `reverse` parameter.

```
var query = require('querystring').parse('reverse=true');
console.log(query); // returns { reverse: 'true' }
```

Note that using `request.query.reverse == true` won't work. Both `==` and `===` will return false. So you'll need to do either `== 'true'` or `==='true'`.

Comment: Great info! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/jackypan1989/express-query-parser

help you to covert all ambiguous string values

Normally you may call http://localhost/?a=null&b=true&c[d]=false.

And get `req.query = {a: 'null', b: 'true', c: {d: 'false'}}`

This project will help you parse to correct value.

`req.query = {a: null, b: true, c: {d: false}}`

Answer (score 0):

do a

```
 console.log(typeof request.query.reverse );
```

I think it's a string but you are checking if the value matches boolean and is true. Either parse the value to boolean or do

```
if (request.query.reverse == true)
```